# Finding the MGF of a bivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, integral, bivariate, moment-generating-function

Given ($X$, $Y$) whose MGF is defined as:

$$M_{XY}(s, t)=E[e^{sX+tY}]$$

Find $M_{XY}(s, t)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are two jointly normal random variables with $E[X]=\mu_X$, $E[Y]=\mu_Y$, $var(X)=\sigma^2_X$, $var(Y)=\sigma^2_Y$, and $\rho(X, Y) = \rho$?

I am so confused about this question. Every method I try seems to land in a dead end. So far I have tried using the Law of Unconscious Statistician as well as noting that $sX + tY$ follows Normal distribution but the integral always seems impossible to solve. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

EDIT1

After checking some posts and doing more research I have conducted the following and would like to know if it is a valid method:

Since $(X, Y)$ is jointly normal, we can write:

$$
(X, Y) = (\mu_X, \mu_Y) + \Sigma^{1/2}(Z_1, Z_2)
$$

Where $\Sigma^{1/2}=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_X & \sigma_{XY}/\sigma_X\\ 0 & (\sigma_Y^2-\sigma_{XY}/\sigma_X^2)^{1/2}
\end{bmatrix}$ (Obtained this matrix through Cholesky Decomposition)

Evaluating the above expression gives us:

$$\begin{bmatrix}X \\ Y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu_X + \sigma_X Z_1 + (\sigma_{XY} / \sigma_{X} Z_2) \\ \mu_Y + (\sigma_Y^2 - \sigma_{XY}^2\sigma_X^{-2})^{1/2} \end{bmatrix}$$

Since now X and Y have been decomposed into functions of two independent normal random variables, we can simply multiplying the corresponding MGF of these functions. Is this argument correct? If not could you please tell me which assumption I am making is mistaken. Thank You

Comment: Find the distribution of $Z=sX+tY$ as the expectation of $e^Z$ is quite manageable.

Comment: @Xi’an As far as i know, the distribution of $Z$ Follows a normal distribution since X and Y and jointly normal therefore any linear combination of them is also normal. But finding $E[e^Z]$ still doesn’t seem to be manageable using elementary functions.

Comment: @ArchitKithania https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822020/321264.